# Adaptation of Regular Bike to Disc brakes

Tags: maintenance, frames, parts

I have a DUNLOP SPORT DS 26 Bike. Here is a similar bike:

[image]

I would like to add hydraulic disc brakes at both front and rear.

But the frame or forks do not have anywhere I can mount the Calipers, and the wheels I have are regular ones.

How can I convert my regular wheels to adapt to the Disc brake wheels, and how can I mount the calipers to the frame?

Comment: Welcome to [bicycles.se] @Alberto. I replaced your links with one of the images, and made a few other small changes. If you don't like what I've done, please feel free to undo the changes. Meanwhile, as with all new members, I suggest that take the [tour] so that you can the best out of this site. Cheers

Comment: We've answered this question multiple times (use the search feature) -- In short, if you don't have a disc ready frame+fork (which just requires adding disc wheels of the appropriate size), it isn't economically feasible to do this (it'd be cheaper to get a new bike with disc brakes in many cases). That looks like a BSO which makes it even less good of an idea to add hydraulic discs.

Comment: Even if the frame is "disk-ready" it's still likely cheaper to buy a new bike vs convert the one you have.